# Eclipse Kepler hangs when trying to add a user libraries

Tags: eclipse, freeze

I have a number of user libraries and Eclipse Kepler hangs when tying to add a user libraries.  It hangs when I press Project properties | Java Build Path | Libraries tab | Add Library... | User Libraries button.  I have about 5 user libraries configured.

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Comment: Upgraded to Luna.  Same problem.

Comment: Reboot did not help.  Tried same setup java, Luna in a Win 2008 Server VM.  No issues there.  Are there any logs I can look at to see why the Eclipse user library dialog doesn't come up.

Comment: So, I copied the workspace from the working system to the not working system and that fixed the hang up.  No idea why but it worked